# WebFlux - how to check if Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<MyItem>>> is empty to return 404

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

My code:

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<TreeItem>>> allGroups(
      @PathVariable(value = "email") String email, ServerWebExchange exchange) {

    return Mono.just(
            userGroupService
                .findGroupByEmail(email) //Flux<GroupById>
                .flatMap(getGroups(email)) //Flux<TreeItem>
                .map(TreeItem::getId) //Flux<UUID>
                .collectList() //Mono<List<UUID>>
                .flatMap(getFilteredGroupIdsForUserPrivilege())
                .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable) //Flux<UUID>
                .flatMap(getUserTreeGroups(email)))
        .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
        .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build()); --> is not executed at all when no data are returned
```

When I pass not existing email, my code returns response 200 with empty array: []

In this case I'd like to return `404 error` - why the last line is not executed?

```
.defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

A method getUserTreeGroups:

```
private Function<UUID, Publisher<? extends TreeItem>> getUserTreeGroups(String email) {
    return filteredGroupId -> userGroupService
        .findUserTreeGroup(filteredGroupId, email);
  }
```

And method findUserTreeGroup:

```
public Mono<GroupTreeItem> findUserTreeGroup(UUID groupId, String email) {
    return groupByIdRepo.findById(groupId)
            .flatMap(group -> findChildData(email, group));
  }
```

I want to return to the frontend a list of TreeItem.
And to be honest - I still don't understand when to use `Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<TreeItem>>>` or maybe `Mono<ResponseEntity<List<TreeItem>>>`? What's the difference?

**UPDATE**
After applying the solution from Thomas Andolf:

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<TreeItem>>> userAllTreeGroups(
    @PathVariable(value = "email") String email, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return userGroupService
              .findUserGroupByEmail(email) //Flux<GroupById>
              .flatMap(groupById -> userGroupService.findUserTreeGroup(groupById.getId(), email)) //Flux<TreeItem>
              .map(TreeItem::getId) //Flux<UUID>
              .collectList() //Mono<List<UUID>>
              .flatMap(groupIds ->
                  rolePrivilegesService.filterGroupIdsForUserPrivilege(groupIds, GROUP_USER_READ_PRIVILEGE))
              .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable) //Flux<UUID>
              .flatMap(filteredGroupId -> userGroupService.findUserTreeGroup(filteredGroupId, email)) //Flux<GroupItem>
              .collectList() //Mono<List<TreeItem>>
              .map(ResponseEntity::ok) //Mono<ResponseEntity<List<TreeItem>>>
              .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

But still I have to return Mono>>.

What should me method return in your opinion? 
Mono>> like in your solution???

Comment: Could you add .log operator and share log?

Comment: why are you placing everything into a `Mono.just` ? what does `getUserTreeGroups(email)` return? can you post this bit of code

Comment: A updated my post by adding implementation of 1 method. I want to return a List<TreeItem>

Comment: can you this time actually include what i thought was pretty obvious, the implementation of `findUserTreeGroup` since the code you provided is mearly a meaningless higher level function.

Comment: Added implementation of findUserTreeGroup

Comment: I thought that it is enough when a service returns nothing (with repository --> from DB)... Can You give me some example? FOr example in some flatMap I invoke some service method that in turn invokes some repository method that returns nothing...Should i check if nothing is returned and then explicitly return Flux.empty()? I don't think so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my second comment i asked

> Why are you placing everything into a `Mono.just()`?

And you didn't answer, well if you actually read it, that would of solved it cause that is probably causing your problem.

```
final List<String> strings = Collections.emptyList();

// You are wrapping a flux in a mono for some strange reason?
final Mono<Flux<String>> wrappedFlux = Mono.just(Flux.fromIterable(strings)
        .flatMap(s -> Mono.just("This never gets run"))
).defaultIfEmpty(Flux.just("This never gets run either, because there is a flux in the mono"));
```

rewritten

```
// Can't test it but something in the lines of the following
return userGroupService
            .findGroupByEmail(email) //Flux<GroupById>
            .flatMap(getGroups(email)) //Flux<TreeItem>
            .map(TreeItem::getId) //Flux<UUID>
            .collectList() //Mono<List<UUID>>
            .flatMap(getFilteredGroupIdsForUserPrivilege())
            .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable) //Flux<UUID>
            .flatMap(getUserTreeGroups(email)))
            .collectList()
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

A `Mono<T>` is one will hold one future computation. When someone subscribes to it, it will try to resolve what is in it, and when its inner status turns into `COMPLETED` it will shoot the out out of it.

A `Flux<T>` is the same thing but for many objects. You can think if it as many `Mono<T>`s and same as before, when someone subscribes to it it will try to resolve the issues inside in each and every item in the `Flux<T>` and eject these as soon as the status hits `COMPLETED` for each and every one.

**Nothing happens until you subscribe on a `Mono<T> or a`Flux`.**

If you have a `Mono<Flux<T>>` when you subscribe, it will try to resolve whatever is in it, and what is in it is a `Flux<T>` so that will get shot out directly.

The `Flux<T>` on the other hand, no one has subscribe to, so nothing in it is resolved. It is basically dead, empty, not used.

You are asking me:

*So in your opinion its meaningless/pointless to have Flux inside Mono*

I have just written above, the absolut **basics** of how reactive programming works. You are emitting a `Flux<T>` from a `Mono<T>` that no one has subscribed to.

**and nothing happens unless you subscribe.**

i sugget you read the documentation for reactor from the start, it is very helpful to understand the basic concepts of [reactive programming](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactive.subscribe)

I don't know what you are trying to achive since i don't have your full codebase i have no idea what you are returning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I wrap everything in Mono because I use openapi to generate endpoints and openapi generates every endpoint that returns something like Mono<ResponseEntity...So in your opinion its meaningless/pointless to have Flux inside Mono: Mono<Flux>? And what with Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<TreeItem>>>??? After applying your solution I get the final type 
Mono<ResponseEntity<List<TreeItem>>> - I can't change the method return type... And I think to return ResponseEntity I have to return Mono<ResponseEntity>...  Please take a look at my update

Comment: No i can't help you since i have no idea what your return types are and what you are doing, and you dont seem to have any clue idea either. Please read up on the basics of Reactive programming stack overflow is not a place where you learn reactive programming.

I have answered your question. If you want more help, please produce a minimal reproducable example. that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: and stop updating your questing. I have answered your question. If you want to know the differences between a `Mono<List<T>>` and a `Flux<T>` google, there are several answers out there.

Comment: You're right, maybe my case is too complicated and ont he other hand I don't want to copy thousand of lines of my code... Anyway, thanks to valuable tips, now I know where is the problem

Comment: It's not "too complicated", but you are asking 5 questions, "what about this, and this, and that what should i do, i have no idea, and this and that and that, and should i do like this or like this or whats difference of that"

80% of your questions are documented in the official reactor documentation. If you have more questions, read up in the official documentation. Start small, and when you get the concept and have problems create a small reproducible example and ask a very specific question.

Not "here is my giant codebase, it doesn't work, help".

Answer (score 0):

In simple you can write your return statement like this

```
return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok(yourService.yourMethod()));
```